# Collapse based on row names, but list all collapsed values

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame which I'd like to collapse based on row names, list all the values in a column (see below):

```
 name   value
 nameA  10
 nameA  3
 nameA  5
 nameB  5
 nameC  1
 nameC  44
```

I would like to generate this output:

```
 name   value
 nameA  10,3,5
 nameB  5
 nameC  1,44
```

Can I use aggregate() for this? similar way I sum the values in R?

> sum <-aggregate(cbind(value) ~ name,  data = x , FUN = sum )

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expected output is not actually summing any values.  Rather, you are concatenating them.  You can use the `c` function in your `aggregate` call.

```
aggregate(value ~ name, dat, c)
#    name    value
# 1 nameA 10, 3, 5
# 2 nameB        5
# 3 nameC    1, 44
```

where `dat` is your data.

You could also use `paste`, or `toString` (which is basically `paste(..., collapse = ", "`).

```
aggregate(value ~ name, dat, toString)
#    name    value
# 1 nameA 10, 3, 5
# 2 nameB        5
# 3 nameC    1, 44
aggregate(value ~ name, dat, paste, collapse = ",")
#    name  value
# 1 nameA 10,3,5
# 2 nameB      5
# 3 nameC   1,44
```

Alternatively, you can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, name) %>% summarize(value = toString(value))
#    name    value
# 1 nameA 10, 3, 5
# 2 nameB        5
# 3 nameC    1, 44
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
aggregate(value~name, df, I)
#  name    value
#1 nameA 10, 3, 5
#2 nameB        5
#3 nameC    1, 44
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(value=list(value)), by=name]
```